# SQL server simple query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How to select value from a table if it value is not null,and select a default value if not?.I.E:

```
select coalesce(username,'its null') from tb_user where int_id_user = 0
```

I try to run this query but its not working,i expect to get 'its null' since int_id_user is 0,but it returns NULL.

Comment: Are there any records for int_id_user where the value is zero?

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using (what database)?

Comment: A trick I like to use (when I'm expecting 0 or 1 results) is to have my program look at the first row returned from SELECT x FROM tablename UNION ALL SELECT 'default' as x  -- Not sure if that applies here though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider doing this specific "IS NULL" check in client code verses SQL because it seems a bit hacky to me... but it works.

***Is this what you wanted?***

**The following SQL shows one way to return "its null" if the username is null *OR* if no row exists for int_id_user.**

```
CREATE TABLE #tb_user (
  int_id_user INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(20) NULL
)
GO

/* returns NO ROWS because #tb_user contains no rows */
select coalesce(username,'its null') from #tb_user where int_id_user = 0
GO

/* returns 'its null' if username IS NULL or int_id_user does not exist in the table */
SELECT COALESCE(
    (select username from #tb_user where int_id_user = 0),
    'its null'
) AS username
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select isnull(column, 'default value')
from table
```

[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

Comment: no, it's isnull, not coalesce...  isnull does exactly what you are asking for.  It tests the column for being null, and if it is it returns the second argument instead.

Comment: COALESCE and ISNULL perform the same duty; COALESCE is ANSI syntax.  Read the comments in the question for why neither works.

Comment: Well said Ponies.And ive updated the query,to column name instead "1",and it still returns NULL;

Comment: Sorry, I keep forgetting what coalesce does... :(

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  COALESCE(username, 'its null'), COALESCE(user_last_name, 'its also null')
FROM    (
        SELECT  0 AS param
        ) q
LEFT JOIN
        tb_user
ON      int_id_user = param
```

or, if you only want one field,

```
SELECT  COALESCE
        (
        (
        SELECT  username
        FROM    tb_user
        WHERE   int_id_user = 0
        ),
        'its null'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Telos has it right. Coalesce works like isnull for N columns.

```
COALESCE(column1, column2, 'default value')
```

Is what you'd want to use if you had more than one column to try before using a default.

Your current query would return 1 because 1 is never null.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server (i won't speak for other dbs), then that won't return the result you want anyway.

The syntax is:

```
coalesce(expr1, [expr n,] expr2)
```

In your case, you are saying *"if the int value 1 is null then return me the text 'not null'"*. But the value of 1 can never be null, so you'll never get the desired text.

Comment: COALESCE is ANSI, it's the same on all databases that support it: SQL Server 2000+, Oracle 9i+, MySQL 4+...

Comment: You are right.Actually the code is:select coalesce(username,'nulo') from tb_usuario where int_id_usuario = 0,where username can be NULL

Answer (score 0):

No, this wont work if there is no row being returned - isnull and coalesce will work if there is a null value in the row, but there should be a row to begin with. If there are no rows, then nothing is returned.

If you are using a stored procedure, it might be better to check the rowcount that the query returns and put some default value whenever it is zero.

Also isnull/coalesce will have to be on some column rather than the integer 1.